# Can't run android test app on real device

Tags: java, android

I am starting to learn how to make Android apps and I am very happy about that. However, everything seems to be going wrong for me. I had problems with the sdk (fixed) and with eclipse (why was it crashing?!). But now I just created my new Hello World app and when I connect my phone to the computer (ZTE Skate Acqua, Android 4.0.4, Debbugging enabled) it gives me this in the console:

```
[2014-09-24 22:19:39 - AndroidTest] ------------------------------
[2014-09-24 22:19:39 - AndroidTest] Android Launch!
[2014-09-24 22:19:39 - AndroidTest] adb is running normally.
[2014-09-24 22:19:40 - AndroidTest] Performing me.pta2002.androidtest.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-09-24 22:19:40 - AndroidTest] Automatic Target Mode: using device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-24 22:19:40 - AndroidTest] Uploading AndroidTest.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-24 22:19:41 - AndroidTest] Installing AndroidTest.apk...
[2014-09-24 22:19:42 - AndroidTest] Installation error: Unknown failure
[2014-09-24 22:19:42 - AndroidTest] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-09-24 22:19:42 - AndroidTest] Launch canceled!
[2014-09-24 22:19:44 - AndroidTest] ------------------------------
[2014-09-24 22:19:44 - AndroidTest] Android Launch!
[2014-09-24 22:19:44 - AndroidTest] adb is running normally.
[2014-09-24 22:19:44 - AndroidTest] Performing me.pta2002.androidtest.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-09-24 22:19:45 - AndroidTest] Automatic Target Mode: using device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-24 22:19:45 - AndroidTest] Uploading AndroidTest.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-24 22:19:46 - AndroidTest] Installing AndroidTest.apk...
[2014-09-24 22:19:47 - AndroidTest] Installation error: Unknown failure
[2014-09-24 22:19:47 - AndroidTest] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-09-24 22:19:47 - AndroidTest] Launch canceled!
[2014-09-24 22:21:14 - AndroidTest] ------------------------------
[2014-09-24 22:21:14 - AndroidTest] Android Launch!
[2014-09-24 22:21:14 - AndroidTest] adb is running normally.
[2014-09-24 22:21:14 - AndroidTest] Performing me.pta2002.androidtest.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-09-24 22:21:15 - AndroidTest] Automatic Target Mode: using device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-24 22:21:15 - AndroidTest] Uploading AndroidTest.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-24 22:21:16 - AndroidTest] Installing AndroidTest.apk...
[2014-09-24 22:21:17 - AndroidTest] Installation error: Unknown failure
[2014-09-24 22:21:17 - AndroidTest] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-09-24 22:21:17 - AndroidTest] Launch canceled!
[2014-09-24 22:22:44 - AndroidTest] ------------------------------
[2014-09-24 22:22:44 - AndroidTest] Android Launch!
[2014-09-24 22:22:44 - AndroidTest] adb is running normally.
[2014-09-24 22:22:44 - AndroidTest] Performing me.pta2002.androidtest.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-09-24 22:22:44 - AndroidTest] Automatic Target Mode: using device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-24 22:22:44 - AndroidTest] Uploading AndroidTest.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-24 22:22:45 - AndroidTest] Installing AndroidTest.apk...
[2014-09-24 22:22:46 - AndroidTest] Installation error: Unknown failure
[2014-09-24 22:22:46 - AndroidTest] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-09-24 22:22:46 - AndroidTest] Launch canceled!
[2014-09-24 22:23:48 - AndroidTest] ------------------------------
[2014-09-24 22:23:48 - AndroidTest] Android Launch!
[2014-09-24 22:23:48 - AndroidTest] adb is running normally.
[2014-09-24 22:23:48 - AndroidTest] Performing me.pta2002.androidtest.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-09-24 22:23:50 - AndroidTest] Automatic Target Mode: using device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-24 22:23:50 - AndroidTest] Uploading AndroidTest.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-24 22:23:51 - AndroidTest] Installing AndroidTest.apk...
[2014-09-24 22:23:51 - AndroidTest] Installation error: Unknown failure
[2014-09-24 22:23:51 - AndroidTest] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-09-24 22:23:51 - AndroidTest] Launch canceled!
```

I have no idea what is going on. I know there is an "Unknown failure", but since it's unknown, I don't know what it is. It runs fine on AVD but it takes ages to boot.
(LogCat log: http://pastebin.com/n7fxPcDJ)

Comment: did you check the logcat output for more details?

Comment: Post the contents of your LogCat please.

Comment: How I check LogCat output? Im new to this

Comment: inside of eclipse/what ever IDE your using when you hit debug you will see a panel down the bottom of the screen (like the error panel) it will be called logcat and will have your output.. if you don't see it, have a look through the view menu (probably in debug sub category) and add logcat to your view

Sorry can't give exact way to get logcat up, don't have it infront of me

Comment: Going to check that and post it on the question. Eclipse crashed (i need to buy a new pc!)

Comment: I have a bunch of PGA errors saying that something was not found. I also have Resources Errors

Comment: use http://pastebin.com/ to give us the log

Comment: It would take ages to write the log :/ is there any quicker way?

Comment: Ok that was the log from another thing. Here it is:
http://pastebin.com/n7fxPcDJ

Comment: What is memtrak?  09-24 16:50:01.929: E/memtrack(7490): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
09-24 16:50:01.929: E/android.os.Debug(7490): failed to load memtrack module: -2

Comment: Are you sure you've allowed installation of apps from unknown sources on your test device(s)? See http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/open-distribution.html#unknown-sources

Comment: I have no idea and yes, I am so used to install cracked games that I am sure its enabled :P